# What will be the bean scope of a solr server in spring

Tags: java, spring, solr

I am having a external solr server, I am creating a SolrServer instance using the following code.

```
 package solr.test;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SolrServerBean {

    @Bean()
    public SolrServer getServer() {
        return new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/");
    }
}
```

If I am autowiring the bean I am able to work, but I want to know whether I have to change the scope of the solr server bean, such that the solr instance can be reused for the whole application,not for a single request.

Comment: By default, the scope of the bean will be Singleton.

Comment: Whether singleton scope will serve all the request using the same bean?

Comment: Right, the singleton behaves just like any other object once it is created. It has no special cases for multi-threaded applications, no protections against concurrent activities, and no inherent synchronization. You must write all those protections yourself